# How to upgrade DataAnnotations for Entity Framework 5 Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to upgrade from EF 4.3.1 to EF 5 and also changing from .Net 4 to .Net 4.5. Here's an example of a class that's giving me trouble:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyClass
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int CompositeKey1Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompositeKey2Id { get; set; }
}
```

First I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'Column'`.

So I add 
`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` since the ColumnAttribute moved into the Schema namespace. Now I get an `Ambiguous reference` error since ColumnAttribute exists in both EntityFramework.dll and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll.

So I try removing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll as a reference and now I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'Key'` since KeyAttribute was in that dll, but not in EntityFramework.dll.

Unless the KeyAttribute isn't needed anymore in EF5, I'll have to *downgrade* to .Net 4 to get this code to compile. That can't be right, is it? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to uninstall EF, then retarget your project to 4.5 then install EF. If you first re-install EF you will end up with EF5 for .NET Framework 4 (assembly version 4.4.0.0) which contains data annotations since they were not in .NET Framework 4 and data annotations from System.Data.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll where the data annotations were moved to in .NET Framework 4.5. On .NET Framework 4.5 you want to have EF5 for .NET Framework 4.5 (assembly version 5.0.0.0) and this should fix the problem. If you already retargeted the project just uninstall and reinstall EF.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out about the same time you answered.